# Add file to org-agenda-files from another agenda file?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have one file that is my default file in `org-agenda-files` (which I set in my `init.el` file).

How can I add other files to the `org-agenda-files` list from within my default agenda file with paths relative to the default file?

Hypothetical example:

```
* One heading
  Some text
* Second heading (external)
  AGENDAFILE: ext/ext.org
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [file-local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) to evaluate a lisp form that will add another file to your `org-agenda-files` list.

For example, you could put the following at the end of your default agenda file to add the `another-agenda-file.org` file to the list.

```
## Local Variables:
## eval: (add-to-list 'org-agenda-files "another-agenda-file.org" 'append)
## End:
```

The `append` argument (or any non-`nil` value) in the call to [`add-to-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html) puts the file at the back of the list.  Leaving it off will put the file at the front of the list.

Comment: Unfortunately it works only in the end of file (or in the first line using another syntax). But it's better than nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way is to set the `org-agenda-files` variable to a directory instead of a file. Thus, any file in the directory will be tracked.

I have not tested it yet but I am pretty sure that it also works with symlinks, so this would work in almost any scenario.

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384907/6537892) on SO.